# Prototype concept in Javascript, am I getting it right?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Person(name, age, gender) {
    (this.name = name), (this.age = age), (this.gender = gender);
}
Person.prototype.eyecolor ="black";

var myFather = new Person("Singh", "50", "Male");
console.log(myFather.eyecolor);
console.log(myFather);
console.log(Person);
```

myFather inherits from Person.prototype using
`__proto__` which links myFather to `Person.prototype` (`myFather.__proto__ === Person.prototype`) and this Person constructor function inherits from `Function.prototype` and this Function has inherited from `Object.prototype` and this is why it's said everything in javascript is essentially an object.

Have I understood this thing right? I have commented on what I have understood here in Prototypes in JS. At this point in time, I don't know the practical use of this concept. Maybe when I learn more I might see some use of it.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Why are you doing `(this.xxxx = name), ....`

Comment: well no I didn't do it intentionally, I had written it like this.name = name; this.age = age but codepen formatted it this way.

Comment: What kind of an answer are you expecting to get for this question? Only yes/no, or do you want to know more about OOP and applying it?

Comment: ES6 now has classes that hide the prototypes away and look more like other object orientated languages.

Comment: I am only expecting yes or no. thanks

Comment: The answer is yes.  BUT.  You are using an outdated technique.

Comment: Normally you would not attach an eyecolor to the prototype, that makes all people have black eyes. You would attack eyecolor to the instance so only that individual instance of a person has black eyes. The prototype is usually used for methods and data that apply to every type of that object.

Comment: @GirkovArpa How is it outdated? Classes are using the same technique under the hood, with just a bit more spices.

Comment: Mate it took me hours to get this thing down and you saying its outdated technique. I feel sorry for myself now.

Comment: It is good to know how the language works. I remember prototypes doing my head in when I first encountered them, but in modern JS programming we rarely think in terms of it any more.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Attaching it to the prototype makes it the default eye color, but you can override it in each instance.

Comment: Okay I stand corrected then.  According to previous comments you are NOT doing it the right way.  Regardless, I posted an answer that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have understood this correct. This concept is called the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in *Javascript*.

> JavaScript objects have a link to a prototype object. When trying to access a property of an object, the property will not only be sought on the object but on the prototype of the object, the prototype of the prototype, and so on until either a property with a matching name is found or the end of the prototype chain is reached.

Basically this will go all the way back until it reaches the *object object*, which all *Javascript* types inherit from, whose `__proto__` is null.

Please note that there are two properties existing, which are basically the same: `__proto__` and `prototype`. The distinction is that only functions have the `prototype` property, while all objects have the `__proto__` property. The `__proto__` property is non-standard, but most browsers have it [implemented](https://caniuse.com/#search=__proto__), so it is save to use.

Answer (score -4):

In this example, the child inherits the last name of the father:

```js
class Father {
  constructor() {
    this.lastName = 'Singh';
    this.age = 50;
    this.gender = 'male';
    this.eyecolor = 'black';
  }
}

class Child extends Father {
  constructor(name, gender, age) {
    super();
    this.firstName = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const myFather = new Father();
console.log(myFather); // { lastName: 'Singh', age: 50, gender: 'male', eyecolor: 'black' }
const mySelf = new Child('Saurav', 'male', 20);
console.log(mySelf.firstName, mySelf.lastName); // Saurav Singh
```

Comment: Should I add a child to illustrate inheritance of eyecolor?

Comment: The question is about the underlying prototype concepts, not just syntax.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Appreciate your time.

Comment: yes please add the child, not for eyecolor maybe for something else. some other example.

Comment: I updated the example to show the child inheriting the last name of the father.  It's an awkward example in that you probably wouldn't use it exactly like this, but it does illustrate how `extends` works.